# how to bring the Content of the dropdown menu button on top of the page displayed within my main.html using frameset tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

My main.html displays the menu.htm and welcome.htm using frameset. Drop down menu buttons "Admin..." and "Scheduler..." suppose to show dropdown content on mouse hover. Since welcome.htm is on top of menu.htm therefore content of the dropdown button doesn't show up.
However, All menu button work as expected when open the menu.htm as standalone page(see attached pic)[menu.htm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80LXQ.png)  But drop-down buttons content does not show up when open in main.html using frame tags.

main.html

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Main Menu</title> 
  
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"></meta>
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />

 </head>
 <frameset rows = "25,*" >
    <frame frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"  scrolling="no" id="menu_frame1"
            name="menu_frame" src="menu.htm" />
        <frame frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"  scrolling="auto"
            id="content_frame1" name="content_frame" src="welcome.htm" />
    </frameset>
</html>
```

Here is menu.htm

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"></meta>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <title>Main Menu</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body
            {
                background-color: #333;
                border: 0px;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                FONT-SIZE: 15px;
                FONT-FAMILY: sans-serif;
            }
                      
                        .topnav 
                          {
                                overflow: hidden;
                                background-color: green;
                                
                          }

                      .topnav a 
                         {
                               float: left;
                               color: #fec10d;
                               font-size: 15px;
                               text-align: center;
                               text-decoration: none;
                font-weight: none;
                padding-left: 10px;
                padding-right: 10px;
                               
                         }


                     .topnav a:hover 
                        {
                              background-color: #ddd;
                              text-decoration: underline;
                              color: black;
                        }


                    .topnav a.active 
                       {                                 
                                 margin-top: 5px;
                                 
                       }

                  .topnav-right 
                      {
                                float: right;
                      }

            
                      .dropdown 
                       {
                               float: left;
                               overflow: hidden;
                       }

                     .dropdown .dropbtn 
                       {
                               font-size: 15px;  
                               border: none;
                               outline: none;
                               color: #fec10d;
                               padding: 5px 7px;
                               background-color: inherit;
                               font-family: inherit;
                               margin: 0;
                       }

                      .topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn 
                       {
                              background-color: #fec10d;
                              color: white;
                             
                       }

                    .dropdown-content 
                       {
                             display: none;
                             position: absolute;
                             background-color: #f9f9f9;
                             min-width: 90px;
                             box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
                             z-index: 1;
                       }

                   .dropdown-content a 
                      {
                            float: none;
                            background-color: #582c83;
                            color: white;
                            padding: 5px 7px;
                            text-decoration: none;
                            display: block;
                            text-align: left;
                      }

                  .dropdown-content a:hover 
                     {
                            background-color: #fec10d;
                     }

                 .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content 
                    {
                           display: block;
                    }

        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function open_in_content(url)
            {
                parent.document.getElementById("content_frame").src = url;
            }
            function open_in_new(url)
            {
                window.open(url);
            }
    
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
               <div class="topnav">
        <a class="active" href="/mainmenu" target="_top">Home</a>
        <a class="active" href="/acctlist" target="content_frame">Accounts</a>
                <a class="active" href="/reports/main" target="content_frame">Customers</a>

               <div class="dropdown">  
               <button class="dropbtn">Admin...<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button> 
               <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="/systems/add">Add Account</a>
            <a href="/filelist">Files</a>
            <a href="/rule/list">Add Rule</a>
            <a href="/planupdate">Account Update</a>
            <a href="/ref/upload">Ref Upload</a>
            <a href="/stats/space">Check stats</a>
        </div> 
              </div>

               <div class="dropdown"> 
           <button class="dropbtn">Scheduler...<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button> 
               <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="/newsystems/add">New Job</a>
            <a href="/newsystems/rem">Remove Job</a>
            <a href="/check">Add checkpoint</a>

        </div> 
              </div>


        <a class="active" href="help/index.htm" target="content_frame">Help</a>

          </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is welcome.htm

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<TITLE>
Main Menu Welcome Page
</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
Use the links at the top of the menu to navigate.
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all Why not use html5?

You should use iframe instead of frame

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe

after, you add id to iframe and you add display option or you add "position:absolute;z-index" these iframes with css.
after, then was mouseover in iframe you change z-index option with javascript

Comment: Thanks Berk.
I tried using iframe but could not really make it work. Whole idea to use frame is so that menu.htm can stay on top of every page and all pages/content open in 2nd frame i.e. content_frame.
Can you refer to any sample code to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I help you but first
Can you review jquery.load()
https://api.jquery.com/load/

I think it might be easier for you.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
       </head>
       <body>
    
        <div id="divMenu"></div>
    
    
      </body>
      </html>
       <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#divMenu").load("./menu.html");//.txt or html or  url
    
       });
       </script>
```

Comment: Thanks again, Sorry I'm new to jquery but this code doesn't seem to be loading menu.html.

Answer (score 0):

try this

Even if the scroll  page, the menu will remain at the top.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        body{background-color:#333}
        *{margin:0;padding:0;border:0}
        .menuBar{width:100%;height:50px;position:fixed;left:0;top:0;z-index:999;background-color:#111;}
        .content{float: left;width:100%;margin-top:50px;height:100vh;}
    </style>
   </head>
   <body>
    <iframe class="menuBar" src="./menu.html" ></iframe>
    <iframe class="content" src="./welcome.html" ></iframe>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Problem with this code is that it only displays partial drop down items. Since you specified the height=50px so it only display menu drop down item until 50x and adds verical scroll bar for rest. If I increase height=200px then content of welcome.html doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

try this
I made the "manubar "background transparent and when mouseover and manubar the height will automatically 300px

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        body{background-color:#333}
        *{margin:0;padding:0;border:0}
        .menuBar{width:100%;height:50px;position:fixed;left:0;top:0;z-index:999;background-color:transparent;}
        .content{float: left;width:100%;margin-top:50px;height:100vh;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe class="menuBar" src=".menu.html" ></iframe>
    <iframe class="content" src="./welcome.html" ></iframe>
    
</body>
</html>

<script>
var menuBar = document.querySelector(".menuBar")
menuBar.onmouseover = function(){
    menuBar.style.height="300px"
}
menuBar.onmouseout = function(){
    menuBar.style.height="50px"
}
</script>
```